# facebook share/apprequest dialog size (mobile)

Tags: javascript, facebook, mobile, facebook-app-requests, facebook-ui

I would like to know can I change the apprequest dialog size in mobile version?
I tried .FB_UI_Dialog to change the width, but it will change all dialog. I only want to change apprequest and share dialog

Comment: did you make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with.

```
 .FB_UI_Dialog {
width: 400px !important; 
}
```

Take a look at [!important how and when use it](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/11/02/the-important-css-declaration-how-and-when-to-use-it/)